# Javascript 'onclick' table issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I do apologize for the title, I wasn't sure what to call this. Anyways I am currently working on a WYSIWYG site builder and I've run into a little problem.

I created the following code to automatically make a 'div' appear above the selected cell for some buttons to be contained within it. The 'div' needs to disappear when a user clicks on another cell or when the user clicks on another bit of the document, etc. But I've been unable to figure out a good method of getting rid of it, would be lovely to have some help. Thank you, and also if it isn't too much to ask. I've been attempting to figure out a way for the document to automatically detect what table index is selected from where the user has their cursor. That can be seen on line 1.

http://jsfiddle.net/fwZTc/102/

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
var cells = table.getElementsByTagName("td"); // 

for(var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++){
// Cell Object
var cell = cells[i];
// Track with onclick


cell.onclick = function(){
    var cellIndex  = this.cellIndex;  

    var rowIndex = this.parentNode.rowIndex;

    alert("cell: " + cellIndex + " / row: " + rowIndex );

//var div = document.createElement('div');
//div.innerHTML = "my <b>new</b> skill - <large>DOM maniuplation!</large>";
// set style
//div.style.color = 'red';
// better to use CSS though - just set class
//div.setAttribute('class', 'myclass'); // and make sure myclass has some styles in css
//document.appendChild(div);


awesome = table.rows[rowIndex].cells[cellIndex];
awesome.innerHTML = '<div style="width:200px; height:20px; position:absolute; margin-top:-20px; background-color:#666">'
}
}
```

Comment: will you use jquery in your project ?

Comment: I use it, but I try to avoid it as much as possible.

Comment: Better start using it. It makes life easier.

Comment: I'm more old school, haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead.

**HTML:**

```
<table>
<tbody id="myTblBody">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td> 
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('#myTblBody tr td').click(function(){
  var html = $(this).html();
  $('#box').remove();
  $(this).html(html + '<div id="box" style="width:50px; height:20px; position:absolute;             margin-top:-20px; background-color:#666">');
  //If you would like to know row and col number.
  var row = $(this).parent().index();
  var col = $(this).index();
  alert('row ==' + row + "col == "+ col);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pq4Mm/)

Comment: This works great, but it is lacking a big feature. I need it to detect what table I have selected, because I have no idea how many tables my users will actually use, and this will only work if there was a single named table. Would there be a way for it to detect what table was selected?

Comment: My mistake, this is what I get for staying up all night. Thank you, you got it 100% correct.

Comment: Yes, you can add `class` instead. Please check this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hsLB7/). is this what you look for ?

Comment: Would there be a way to make it so that the 'box' would always be in the top right hand side of the table, I've noticed that the div always being on top of the cell is an issue with trying to switch to other cells as well as not always ending on the top if content is involved.

Comment: you can add some css accordingly. check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uRBgC/)

Comment: That does help, but I am still unsure of how to make sure it is always directly in the top right hand corner of the table at the very top. So basically if there was a way to get the number of columns and then place the div in the very last column on the very first row, then that would be perfect. I've been looking into it, but I've been able to find anything. @Navin

Comment: Exactly like that actually. @Navin